# Mouse/touchpad toggle in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

How to tune Ubuntu to automatically deactivate a touchpad on mouse connect and activate on its disconnect?

Comment: ~~~~> SuperUser

Answer (score 1):

You can manually disable an input device via:

`xinput set-int-prop "B16_b_02 USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 'Device Enabled' 8  0`

and reenable it via:

`xinput set-int-prop "B16_b_02 USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse" 'Device Enabled' 8  1`

You can get the list of device names via:

`xinput list`

If you want to automate the whole process you could write a script to listen to HAL, which will tell you when devices are plugged in or removed. As a starting point you can have a look at [xboxdrv-daemon.py](http://github.com/Grumbel/xboxdrv/blob/8d80fa7c497d6e05c3c4215e239915a8dc6ee18e/tools/xboxdrv-daemon.py)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this thread?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1123428) Looks like they're almost there.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command in the Awesome startup script:

```
lsusb | egrep -i 'Mouse' > /dev/null && synclient TouchpadOff=1 || synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an old Compaq Armada 110, and just installed Ubuntu.

I have connected a PS/2 mouse, which the system cannot see. On the other hand it can see the touchpand as a PS/2 vitual mouse.

Can i change this so that i could only use the PS/2 mouse and not the touchpad ?